# What's the difference between ln -s and alias?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, command-line

I just found a workaround for a [problem](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html) I was having with the `subl` command for Sublime Text 3 when the MacPorts version of python is installed. The instructions say to put a soft link, `ln-s` to the command line app in your /bin. That didn't work, so I just opened my ~/.profile and added an alias:
    `alias subl="/Applications/path/to/subl"`.
But that begs a new question for me. What is the difference between these two: alias and soft links?

Comment: A word of caution, to save some readers the confusion I just experienced. In this question, and most (but [not all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18453311/4913575)) of the answers, the word "alias" is referring to the `alias` command found in many shells in Unix, Linux, etc. See, for example, [The alias Command](http://www.linfo.org/alias.html) at LINFO. That is in contrast with the very different meaning of "alias" in the context of OS X and MacOS. See, for example, [Alias (Mac OS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(Mac_OS)) at Wikipedia.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

They're entirely different things, though in this case they can be used for similar purposes.

This:

```
alias subl="/Applications/path/to/subl"
```

creates an alias, so that typing `subl` as a shell command is equivalent to typing `/Applications/path/to/subl`.

In bash, functions are generally preferred to aliases, because they're much more flexible and powerful.

```
subl() { /Applications/path/to/subl ; }
```

Both these things are specific to the shell; they cause the shell to expand `sub1` to a specified command.

`ln -s`, on the other hand, creates a *symbolic link* in the file system.  A symbolic link is a reference to another file, and for most purposes it can be treated as if it were the file itself. It applies to anything that accesses it, not just to the shell, it's immediately visible to all processes running on the system, and it persists until it's removed. (A symbolic link is implemented as a small special file containing the name of the target file.)

Comment: Keith, can you provide a reference to why functions are preferred to aliases (especially for cases like this)?  For example, this answer says otherwise: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30950 Thanks!

Comment: @cjerdonek: No, I don't have a reference. There's nothing wrong with aliases, but functions are much more powerful. Anything you can do with an alias, you can do with a function.

Answer (score 36):

An Alias is a **Macintosh Finder concept**. When you make an Alias in the Finder, the Finder tracks it. When you move the original file or folder, the alias follows it.

A symbolic link is a **Unix File System concept**. When you make a symbolic link, it merely points to the original location. Move the original, and the symbolic link will point nowhere.

When you use a Mac application, and use the Open/Save dialog box, it will handle aliases because it uses the Finder API, and the Finder handles alias tracking.

Unix tools don't integrate with the Finder API, so can't track aliases. However, they work with the underlying Unix API which handles symbolic links. You can use `ls` on a symbolic link because it uses the Unix API. Same with Python.

Back in the System 7/8/9 days, the file system couldn't handle symbolic links much like the Windows API uses shortcuts and not symbolic links. You needed aliases.

However, Mac OS X is a Unix based OS, so understands the concept of symbolic links. The Finder now treats symbolic links as it did aliases (except that symbolic links don't update when the original moves). The only reason for aliases is to be compatible with the old Finder file system.

Comment: Finder alias are similar to sym links, but the alias that the OP has created is a shell alias, not a Finder alias. That is just a text-replacement-type shortcut to typing the full name of the file. It won't show up in a Finder window, but only work when typed in a terminal window.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, but @beroe is right. The alias I created applies only to the shell and won't show up in Finder.

Comment: Sorry, I saw the Mac OS, and I thought you were asking the difference between the Finder Alias and the Unix OS Symbolic link. In Unix, an alias is a shell concept and not an OS concept. Not all Unix shells support aliases (like the original Bourne shell). In shells that support aliases, the alias is detected only if it is used like a command, and the command string is executed instead, but without a shell replacement. You won't see an alias being substituted in you have `set -xv` on.

Comment: This answer answers the question that makes more sense than the one that was asked :)

Comment: You say that "the only reason for aliases is to be compatible with the old Finder file system". But isn't the Finder's ability to track aliases when originals are moved a decent enough reason to use them?

Comment: How are MacOS aliases implemented? Thats the important question. I find it barely useful  to use vague language like "Finder API", we need implementation. I read about them storing the inode and searching for them (which is impossible on unix because of the permission system) but i have not find details on it yet.

Answer (score 7):

It is really a super question

There are 3 levels of aliases in this debate

1. **File system:** ln -s "target-file-or-directory" "alias" - this is visual for all programs using the file system (bash, Finder, applications)
2. **Shell alias:** (bash/sh/zsh etc) - (part of question) - only used by shell command line
3. **MacOS Finder:** "make alias" - Known by Finder, and file dialogue box in most applications

Some different use cases:

- Want shell scripts (bash) to navigate your file system in a symbolic way - then use **ln -s ...** When you install **java** it will use this technique it self. In example try to say **which java** and see where java is. Then use **ls -a /usr/bin/java** to see where is really is.
- Want to do fast links in Finder so you can navigate to common things that happens to be located in different directories --> use **Finder make alias**
- Want to start Sublime editor with a short cut from bash then use **Shell alias**. I have alias **ll=ls -l** - that lists a directory one item per line. I hardly cannot use **bash** without it :-) Note these substitutions only takes place on the command line substitution in **bash** and is therefore less useful in shell scripts.

Personally I use **ln -s ..** relative often.

I also use **Finder make alias** a lot. It is easy and links follows the items as they more around. But it does not work from **bash** - therefore I sometimes changes these links to **ln -s ...* when I need to start scripting.

Answer (score 2):

`ln -s` creates a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), which is almost a file on your filesystem

[alias](http://www.ss64.com/bash/alias.html) is a shell specific thing

So, basically, a symbolic link is a better solution because it is going to work for everything. Like, if you want to make your file manager open text files with that specific program, you can point it to your symbolic link and it is going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Aliases only exists within the context of the shell (Bash, Sh, Zsh, etc.) but is not found in other applications whereas `ln -s` creates a virtual file (a link that is) to an existing real file that could present itself like a new command and should be cognizable by most applications that calls other binaries. Aliases are similar to functions and variables only that they are more like command templates. Creating a function actually is more commendable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be missing something in your alias command above -- it should have the form `alias mumble="substitution"` and will cause any command you type beginning with mumble to be replaced by substitution.  So if what you entered in your profile was `alias subl="/Applications/path//to/subl"` then whenever you type subl at the start of a command, it is replaced by the full path.

`ln` works by creating a reference in the file system from one thing to another.

The link you provide above suggests that `ln` will not work with the version of Python provided in MacPorts.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Another comment leads me to realize the alias I'm talking about is a mac-specific 'finder' alias, whereas the aliases in question here are bash 'shell' aliases. My mistake.

A symbolic, or soft, link points to a path: a location on the filesystem. If the file or folder located at the path is moved or renamed, the soft link will now point at nothing useful.

An alias can contain a reference to a path, or to a file ID, or both, depending on the implementation. On Mac OS X at least, the default is both, but the path is favoured over the file ID. That is, as long as something exists at the path referenced by your alias, your alias will point to the path, *just like a symbolic link does.* But, if nothing exists at the path referenced by your alias, it will instead point to the original file ID.

For example:

Suppose you create a file, and then create an alias for it, by specifying the file path. The alias now contains the file's file ID, as well as the file's path. The alias will by default follow the file's path to take you to the file.

If you now move the file to a different location, the alias will follow it by referencing the file's file ID. But, if you assign a NEW file to the same file path as the old one, the alias will now point to the new file, since it favours path over file ID.

Reference: http://forums.macworld.com/index.php?/topic/142842-aliases-vs-symbolic-links/

Comment: With File ID do you mean the inode number?  Or is this something stored with the file? Unfortunately the bad Unix file API forces most programs to use atomic rename for saving instead of atomic content swapping (breaking the inode). If it's not the inode how we know it will survive a file edit? Unofrtunately your link does not work anymore.