# Why is an alias on macOS so much larger than a symbolic link?

Tags: macos, alias, symlink

When I create an alias on macOS in Finder's GUI via command-alt drag and drop it creates an alias file about 1.2 MB in size. In contrast, when I use `ln -s [file]` on the shell it takes up 114 bytes. Why does the the alias file have to be so big?

Comment: Because they are completely different things. One can be tracked by the Finder (e.g if you move the original file to some other place, the Finder will still point to the correct, new, location), while the shell one will point to nowhere anymore. And you can see by e.g `nano yourfile_alias` in the case of the Finder alias, you'll get the alias file content, while in the case of the shell alias, you'll get the original file's (or nothing if original file moved)

Comment: @Kaiido So *what* makes aliases so big then? What *is* in the alias file's content?

Comment: Finder aliases? Fast reading one's content with nano, I would say it stores the original location, the protocol, a UUID of the original file along with some other info I'm not able to guess what it is, probably some info about the icon to display too. A very related answer;, even though it didn't answered the question it was posted on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18453311/3702797